# Regex remove everything after 2nd dash

Tags: regex

I have a large amount of data that I need to filter using Regex. The data consists of strings that look like this:

```
60166213

60173866-4533

60167323-9439-1259801

NL170-2683-1262201

60174710-1-A12-4
```

When I need them to look like this:

```
60166213

60173866-4533

60167323-9439

NL170-2683

60174710-1
```

How can I filter with regex to remove everything after and including the 2nd dash. The number of dashes varies, and I need to retain all strings 'as is' that do not contain more than one dash.

Comment: What flavour of regular expressions? What did you try?

Comment: I have tried all the below examples with no luck. I should have mentioned this but I'm using Universal Analytics which uses regex in PERL. I don't believe that UA allows the use of Lookback as it is a restricted library.

Comment: I don't know 'UA', but is it possible to do it without regex? Something like `if mystring.count('-') >= 2 then split and take first two parts`?

Comment: This can be done without regex, using `split`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(.*?-.*?)-.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO7hD2/2)**

[image]

You can check on **Code generator** link the code for different languages. For `php` that uses PCRE (Perl Comptaible RegEx) engine you can use:

```
$re = "/(.*?-.*?)-.*/"; 
$str = "60166213\n\n60173866-4533\n\n60167323-9439-1259801\n\nNL170-2683-1262201\n\n60174710-1-A12-4"; 
$subst = "\1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like a winner, however it doesn't seem to work properly - I think this is because I am using a PERL library which does not allow lookback. Is there an alternative that you can think of?

Comment: For example, using your suggestion it removes instances of "60177528-1" which I need to keep. Strange though as I can see from the Code generator that it works perfectly

Comment: @madkeen The example I put is for PCRE regex which mean Perl Compatible Reg Ex. If you are using Perl it should work

Comment: @madkeen you can help yourself with anchors, for instance: `^(.*?-.*?)-.*$` **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO7hD2/3)**

Comment: your initial solution worked - for some reason I needed to wait overnight for the filter to work properly in UA. 

Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
results = [re.sub(r"^([^-]+(?:-[^-]+)?).*$", r"\1", data) for data in datum]
```

Explained

```
re.compile("""
    ^                # assert beginning of string
    (                # begin capturing group
        [^-]+        #   one or more non-hyphen characters
        (?:          #   begin non-capturing group
            -        #     literal hyphen
            [^-]+    #     followed by one or more non-hyphen characters
        )?           #   end non-capturing group, and allow 1 or 0 of them
    )                # end capturing group
    .*               # match the rest of the string
    $                # assert end of string""", re.X)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nF6eW3/1)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned this but I'm using Universal Analytics which uses regex in PERL.

Answer (score 1):

Since no language was specified, a basic regular expression would be the following. In the replacement call, you would use either `\1` or `$1` to reference the matched group.

```
([^-\n]+-[^-\n]+)-.*
```

Comment: I am using a Universal Analtics filter which I believe uses PERL library, however it is restricted in not allowing lookback.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the OP is looking for a regex solution, but it is possible to achieve this without regex.  The following is offered as a simple alternative that might be useful in the given application:

```js
var arr = ['60166213', '60173866-4533', '60167323-9439-1259801', 'NL170-2683-1262201', '60174710-1-A12-4'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var s = arr[i].split('-');
  if (s[1]) {
    var o = s[0] + ' - ' + s[1];
  } else {
    var o = s[0];
  }
  $('#output').append(o + '<br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*\K.*$
```

Simply use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/38